# Can't connect to SQL Server express from .net core app running on docker

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have SQL Server 2016 Express, docker for Windows and IIS installed on my Windows 10 machine.

SQL Server Express is configured to listen on 1455 port. The Northwind sample database is there.

Windows Firewall is disabled.

`Ipconfig` shows the following:

```
Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT) 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::70f1:3323:a7a8:b7a5%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I created a very simple .net core 2 console app in Visual Studio 2017:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConnectSqlServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void TestHttp()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var response = client.GetAsync("http://10.0.75.1").Result;
                var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestHttp();
            var cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.0.75.1\\SQLEXPRESS,1455;Initial Catalog=Northwind;User ID=docker;Password=SomeStrongPassword;");
            cn.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

The app runs successfully when running on Windows from Visual Studio. But when I add Docker Support and run it, the TestHttp method works ok, but I cannot connect to SQL Server, I get the following exception:

> **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.0-runtime
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConnectSqlServer.dll"]
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  connectsqlserver:
    image: connectsqlserver
    build:
      context: ./ConnectSqlServer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

What should I do to connect to local SQL Server Express running on the Windows host from a .net core 2.0 app running on a docker container?

EDIT:

Answer: Be careful when disabling Windows Firewall.

I turned off Windows Firewall, but only on Domain networks. Windows sees the DockerNAT adapter as a public network. So Windows firewall was blocking the connection to SQL Server.

I turned off Windows Firewall on public networks and I can connect now.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145881/can-not-connect-to-sql-server-from-docker-supported-asp-net-core-project?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was I didn't disable Windows Firewall correctly.

I turned off Windows Firewall, but only on Domain networks. Windows sees the DockerNAT adapter as a public network. So Windows firewall was blocking the connection to SQL Server.

I turned off Windows Firewall on public networks and I can connect now.

Answer (score 1):

For me what did the trick was to set Server attribute in the connection string, with IP,Port.

```
Server=10.10.0.27,1433;Database=database;User id=user;password=pwd;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well what worked for me is, changing localhost to 127.0.0.1. I didn't have to disable any of the Firewall.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to start the container using network mode as host. In that case the container can connect to applications running on the host machine using **localhost** as a DNS name.

```
version: '3'

services:
  connectsqlserver:
    image: connectsqlserver
    build:
      context: ./ConnectSqlServer
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    network_mode: "host"
```

Comment: But I can connect to the host machine, I can access to the IIS, TestHttp worked.

Comment: I think network_mode: "host" only works on linux. I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work, even TestHttp method failed.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect to the database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The database and API were on Docker Desktop.

I managed to solve the issue by defining server name as **"localhost,25437"** instead of "host.docker.internal,25437".