# Connecting to SQL Server on host through Windows Server-based container

Tags: sql-server, docker, networking

How do you connect to a SQL Server database on a host (or even in the cloud, as in off the local network) from a windows server-based container?
I've tried using

```
docker run --net="nat" ...
```

and

```
docker run --net="host" ...
```

to no avail.
Using -p does not seem relevant as I want to container to talk to the SQL Server database not running in a container.
I'm not sure how a custom network bridge can work here but I'm open to trying.

Comment: The default network should allow connecting to a remote host. Have you tested connectivity from the running container, e.g. `docker exec -it your-container cmd /C"ping <remote-host-ip>"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to SQL Server express from .net core app running on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409215/cant-connect-to-sql-server-express-from-net-core-app-running-on-docker)

Comment: `networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat` in docker compose file helped me connect to sql server from conatiners